# files.find query for extension

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to list only files with a particular extension?

I tried "title contains '.mm'" but this returns no results, although there is a file like that in Drive. I also tried "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.mm', no luck as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
fileExtension = 'mm'
```

Comment: is this an undocumented feature? the API doc page https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters does not have this parameter

Comment: @GojkoAdzic Yeah it's apparently undocumented.

Comment: fileExtension property returns nil if the file was originally saved with the extension included in the file name. For example, if you set the 'file.name' property as 'test.myextension', the fileExtension property would return nil in this case. To work with the extension property properly, you need to set the file.extension property when saving.